# Put repetitive code inside of function or custom class?

Tags: python, function, class, dry

I know custom classes are very handy in OOP and in Python. You can have objects with pre-defined properties.

I have several functions in Python with a repetitive code in the beginning of the function definition.

It should be some DRY solution, may be based on making a class for this functions but my googling yielded me nothing.

How is it done in Python?

UPD. Here is an example.

```
def my_function1():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--someargument')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

There are three lines which have to be repeated in my_function2, my_function3, etc.

UPD 2.

The starting lines are easily solved with a function (see the answer of MattDMo). But how can I DRY (do not repeat yourself) with ending lines in my_function(s):

```
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    pickle.dump(cookies, open('cookies.pkl', 'wb'))

    driver.close()
```

The solution I found is something like this. First defining a varialbe with the desired chunk of code (like macro):

```
chunk_of_code = '''
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
pickle.dump(cookies, open('cookies.pkl', 'wb'))
driver.close()
'''
```

and inserting in the end of my_function:

```
    exec(chunk_of_code)
    return something
```

It's quick and dirty but it works for my simple programs temporarilly.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why not put the repeated code in a separate function, and simply call that function in the other function definitions?

Comment: I agree, it sounds like all you need is a function.

Comment: OOP is for packaging lots of functions that operate on a common set of data. If you just have repeated code, use an ordinary function.

Comment: You can also use decorators (https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/): special functions that can "wrap" another functions. Kind of metaprogramming in Python

Comment: @MattDMo please check my example in the edited question. Looks like I can't just def a function with the repetitive code and call it inside my target function. At least, it didn't work when I tried before asking the question.

Comment: @user996142, yes I know about the decorators but it's a kind of overkill in my situation. It's not so easy for a novice to master the decorators. Isn't there any other ways of putting a few lines of a repetitive code?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson see my answer. You need to `return` the results of your function so it can be used by the enclosing function.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't `return`ing the results of `my_function1()` so that it can be used by the other functions. Try this:

```
def setup_webdriver(arg="--generic_argument"):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument(arg)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver # this is the important part

def first_real_function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...):
    arg = "--real_argument_one"
    driver = setup_webdriver(arg)
    # continue other work with driver using --real_argument_one

def second_real_function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...):
    arg = "--real_argument_two"
    driver = setup_webdriver(arg)
    # continue other work with driver using --real_argument_two
```

Comment: Eventually, this is something I ended up with. But can you please check my update 2?